# App/Website to make maps

Tags: osx, maps, google-maps

I want to take a map of the earth, and put three overlays on top: ie an overlay of all forests in green, an overlay of all waterfalls in blue, and an overlay of all deserts in yellow. So, in the end, I want software that would enable me to do something like this: [image]